# sys_nanosleep inhibits movement of cursor in terminal

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, system-calls

I am making a snake game in x86-64 assembly for Linux using syscalls and basic c stdlib. I made a function to set the cursor position in the terminal that is called at each iteration of the game loop after having waited 1 second (1s for debugging, much less in the real game). If I don't sleep, the cursor moves successfully but it doesn't if I do.
Here is my code:

```
global main

extern putc
extern printf
extern fflush

%define MAP_WIDTH  20
%define MAP_HEIGHT 20
%define MAP_COUNT  (MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT)

%define SCREEN_WIDTH  (MAP_WIDTH + 1)
%define SCREEN_HEIGHT MAP_HEIGHT
%define SCREEN_COUNT  (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT)

%define WAIT_TIME_NS (150 * 10^6)

%define MAX_SNAKE_LENGTH MAP_COUNT

section .text

; Functions: rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9
; Syscalls:  rax, rdi, rsi, rdx

clear_console:
    mov rax, 1             ; RAX: Syscall #1     : Write
    mov rdi, 1             ; RDI: File Handle #1 : Stdout
    mov rdx, CLEAR_CMD_LEN ; RDX: Length
    mov rsi, CLEAR_CMD     ; RSI: char*
    syscall                ; Perform the syscall

    ret

sleep_before_next_iteration:
    mov rax, 35             ; RAX: Syscall #35: sys_nanosleep
    mov rdi, SLEEP_TIMESPEC ; RDI: req: pointer to struct timespec.
    xor rsi, rsi            ; RSI: mem: struct timespec* (NULL here)
    syscall                 ; Perform the syscall

    ret

exit_program:
    mov rax, 60  ; RAX: Syscall #60:  Exit
    xor rdi, rdi ; RDI: Error Code 0: Clean Exit
    syscall      ; Call Syscall

    ret

go_to_location: ; Args (rdi: x, rsi: y)
    ; Move Cursor To Position

    mov rdx, rsi             ; Argument 2; %d for y
    mov rsi, rdi             ; Argument 1: %d for x
    mov rdi, MOVE_CURSOR_CMD ; Argument 0: string to format

    call printf

    ret

main:
    call clear_console

game_loop_iterate:
    call sleep_before_next_iteration

    ; Print Apple

    mov rdi, 5 ; goto x
    mov rsi, 7 ; goto y
    call go_to_location

    mov rax, 1             ; RAX: Syscall #1     : Write
    mov rdi, 1             ; RDI: File Handle #1 : Stdout
    mov rdx, 1             ; RDX: Length
    mov rsi, APPLE_STR     ; RSI: char*
    syscall                ; Perform the syscall

    jmp game_loop_iterate

game_loop_end:
    call exit_program

    ret

section .data:
    SLEEP_TIMESPEC: dq 1, 0

    APPLE_STR: db "apple string", 0

    MOVE_CURSOR_CMD: db 0x1B, "[%d;%df", 0

    CLEAR_CMD:     db   27,"[H",27,"[2J"    ; Clear Console Command
    CLEAR_CMD_LEN: equ  $-CLEAR_CMD         ; Length Of The Clear Console Command
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I don't think that `sys_nanosleep` is the root cause of this issue since it just sleeps but I've been searching for about half a day.

Info:

- Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Building:

- `nasm -felf64 -g ./snake.asm`
- `clang snake.o -o snake`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need additional info?

Comment: The output is the same with or without sleeping, just much slower; too slow to wait for the first cursor-movement.  Use `strace -o foo.trace ./snake` to record it.  You get single-char `write` system calls and occasional blocks of 1024 bytes of printf output because stdout is line-buffered by default.

 Make it unbuffered, use fprintf to stderr, or call fflush after each printf. 

(The normal method of printing a `\n` to trigger flushing obviously won't work).  Amusingly, the first google hit for `site:stackoverflow.com cursor movement printf line buffer` was about sleep, like this.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn’t realize that even though I know about the buffering!